# Выбрать записи из таблицы, основываясь на значениях другой таблицы?

Tags: sql

У меня есть две таблицы, одна из которых содержит "группы", а другая - id пользователей, которые состоят в этих группах. Как вывести информацию только о тех группах, в которых больше пользователей, чем указано в поле Count у каждой группы?

Comment: так покажите как выглядат таблицы

Comment: `count() as xx, group by, having xx > y.count`

Comment: @entithat Таблица GroupTable содержит 3 поля: Id, Count, Name. Таблица UserTable содержит два поля: UserId и GroupId. Они связаны через GroupTable.Id = UserTable.GroupId. Мне нужно вывести те записи из таблицы GroupTable, чьи Id существуют в таблице UserTable больше, чем Count этих записей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в общем случае как-то так должно быть

```
SELECT g.id, g.name
FROM groups as g
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id, g.name
HAVING count(u.id) < g.count
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваш вариант оказался верным! А я пошёл зубрить учебник...